# java8-"Optional" check and return

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I need a question about "Optional".

now mycode is like this:

```
if(userInfoDto==null){
    return ApiResult.successMsg("no param");
}
if(StringUtils.isEmpty(userInfoDto.getUserName())){
    return ApiResult.successMsg("no username");
}
if(StringUtils.isEmpty(userInfoDto.getEmail())){
    return ApiResult.successMsg("no email");
}
if(StringUtils.isEmpty(userInfoDto.getPhone())){
    return ApiResult.successMsg("no phone");
}
```

I want to use "Optional" to change it and to check my object and my properties if they are null or not.
But,when I use it.I found that I can't do somethings when I found they are null.
eg:

```
Optional<UserInfoDto> optionalUserInfoVo = Optional.ofNullable(userInfoDto)
                             .orElseGet(#{default});
```

if `userInfoDto==null`

I want to return a `ApiResult<T>` to my FE not default。

and for `UserInfoDto`，I need to return some tips When I checked its property is null.

but if I use `if(){}else{}`

I think the "Optional" losed its function;

How can I do？

Comment: what do you mean "losed it function" ?

Comment: There's not much point having `Optional.ofNullable` immediate followed by `orElseGet` in the same statement. It seems like unnecessary complication. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Optional is designed to solve the "null" used simple grammar like “Stream”。if I create a Optional ，but then I use a “if” to check “isPresent()”.I think ,maybe,I can directly use “if（xxx==null）”

Comment: So if `userInfoDto` is null, you want to return a Banana, and if it is not null you want to return an Airplane. What data type would you use for that? It's not a Fruit or a Vehicle. --- Re-think what you're trying to do.

Comment: I want to change it like` if(userInfoDto==null){
            return ApiResult.successMsg("no param");
        }
        if(StringUtils.isEmpty(userInfoDto.getUserName())){
            return ApiResult.successMsg("no username");
        }
        if(StringUtils.isEmpty(userInfoDto.getEmail())){
            return ApiResult.successMsg("no email");
        }
        if(StringUtils.isEmpty(userInfoDto.getPhone())){
            return ApiResult.successMsg("no phone");
        } ` to Optional.

Comment: maybe，I should not use it  when I want to return some message。Optional can‘t support it.Only set some default value when it is null. thanks.

Comment: `Optional` was created to solve the ambiguity between intentional `null` return values (to denote absent values) and return values which ought to be non-`null` (but could be mistakenly `null`). There was no intent of having developers mindlessly replacing any code dealing with `null` by an `Optional` usage.

Comment: @Holger I agree over the point of wrapping the `Map.of` with `LinkedHashMap`, but have a doubt around the processing order and `NullPointerException` that you called out. Did you mean, the processing order is not guaranteed because of the `Map.of`?

Comment: @Naman no, you had two issues. Even without using `Map.of(..)`, the code would not be formally correct (despite likely working with a sequential stream). When using `Stream.of(Object::isNull, x -> x.someCondition()) .filter(p -> p.test(null)) .findFirst();`, the correct answer is the first predicated according to the *encounter order*, but the construct is relying on the *processing order*, as the second predicate breaks when not being skipped due to an already evaluated first predicate. In practice, this can break with a parallel stream, which might evaluate both predicates at the same time.

Comment: @Holger thanks for your answer.I have to change a way to simplify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s completely pointless. `Optional` is for return values that may be absent and has very few other good uses. Your use case is not one of them. Just to illustrate and warn, you might obtain something like what you are trying with the following construct:

```
    String message = Optional.ofNullable(userInfoDto)
            .flatMap(dto -> Optional.ofNullable(dto.getUserName())
                    .flatMap(un -> Optional.ofNullable(dto.getEmail())
                            .map(em -> {
                                // Do your processing here
                                return "Successfully processed";
                            })))
            .orElse("Something’s wrong here");
    return ApiResult.successMsg(message);
```

**BUT:**

1. It’s clearly less readable than your code in the question.
2. It cannot give different error messages for the different null conditions, only one pretty useless message if there is a null somewhere.

I even simplified the requirements a little. I am checking for null user name and email. If you add the check for null phone number along the same lines, it will degrade readability even further.

Don’t try this at home, kids. :-)

Comment: ok,now I get it! thanks for your answer! In my project,I have few scenes to use "Optional" to solve problem of "check blank".Many {if else} make me feel ugly and  similar。but I should change a way to solve it! thanks very much!